# Detect whether compiled perl script dynamically loads modules

Tags: perl, compilation, par

I am running Windows 10 with Strawberry Perl. I use the *PAR::Packer* module to make executable versions of some of my Perl scripts.

I find that some modules e.g. *XML::LibXML*, require a Perl installation in order to run the executable. Since I'm compiling these for users without Perl this defeats the purpose of the compilation.

Is there any way I can tell before compilation whether or not the executable will need a Perl installation to run?

Comment: I am not sure that the title of the question is apropos. I think that dynamic loading of modules is the issue, but I'm not certain that's the case.

Comment: Maybe you need to tell PAR::Packer to include the modules when packing? See the -c/-x options to `pp`.

Comment: All modules requires a Perl installaion. The PAR::Packer executable provides one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to know, if your pp - packed executable will run on a system with no perl installed, here is how I do it:

Get Process Explorer from sysinternals.com.
Pack your executable.
Run the executable and check the dlls of the process in ProcessExplorer
(*view->'show lower pane'* and *view->'lower pane view'->'DLLs'*)
If you see any dll refering to a path other than the PAR temp-dir or system libraries, which are present on any windows system, go back, pack again and add these libs using pp's -l switch.

Example:

```
pp -e "use XML::LibXML; while(1){sleep 1}"
```

Running ***a.exe*** ...
Process Explorer displays

```
libxml2-2_.dll ... C:\Users\user\perl522\c\bin\libxml2-2_.dll
```

This will not be present on a users system ...
Rerunning pp:

```
pp -l libxml2-2_.dll -e "use XML::LibXML; while(1){sleep 1}"
```

This time, running ***a.exe*** ...
Process Explorer displays:

```
libxml2-2_.dll ... C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\par-xxx\cache-SHA1\libxml2-2_.dll
```

Now the process picks up the lib that was bundled with pp and extracted to PARs cache-dir.

Cheers, Chris

Comment: It was the -l option in pp that I didn't know about. That's the key to resolving the problem.

Comment: I would personally nominate this solution for a Nobel Prize. Problem is everywhere on the web but not clear & direct answer.
Works for me finally after struggling a lot.
I have also noticed that every PC has it's own set of dynamic libraries.
in my case i added " -l libiconv-2_.dll -l liblzma-5_.dll -l libxml2-2_.dll -l zlib1_.dll"