# Perl executable crashes even though file is not missing

Tags: perl, dll, gd

I get the following error:

```
Can't load '...\AppData\Local\Temp\par-6e72616f\cache-20221205133501\5743946b.xs.dll' for module GD:
   load_file:
      The specified module could not be found at <embedded>/DynaLoader.pm line 193.
      at <embedded>/PAR/Heavy.pm line 140.
```

(Line breaks added for readability.)

Here is the file `t2.pl`:

```
use GD;
```

Here is the command to convert it to an exe (I use a batch file that timestamps it):

```
pp -T 20221205133501 -o t2_20221205133501.exe t2.pl
```

On my laptop, the exe works, but on a barebones Citrix environment it fails.

My environment:

- Strawberry Perl v5.32.1 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int
- GD v2.73

I know the file is simple, but that one line is enough to cause the crash.

The file it complains about exists and is located where it is looking.

I have looked and is looks like I need to add `-m GD`, or `-l xxx` to make it work. I tried adding all the dll files I could find for GD, but failed.

I have a corporate environment so I can't really use anything that depends on external programs not in Windows 10. `pp_simple` depends on `wxpar` which I do not have. I have used:

```
objdump -x C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib\auto\GD\GD.xs.dll | find "DLL"
```

which got me a list of DLLs, and I did try using them with `-l`.

Comment: Note that the module in question might not be the .xs.dll, but a DLL used by it.

Comment: You can use process explorer on the machine where you pack the program. It runs without installation under standard user privileges. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53353869/10667839

Answer (score 2):

From [Re: Par with strawberry-Perl](https://www.mail-archive.com/par@perl.org/msg06375.html)

> There are likely missing DLLs that need to be added to the `pp` call
> using the `--link` option.
>
> Finding these manually can be a pain, so have a look at `pp_autolink` or
> `pp_simple` (the former is mine, but adapted from the latter).
>
> - https://github.com/shawnlaffan/perl-pp-autolink
> - https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1148802